# In JMeter java.net.SocketException: Connection reset is occuring

Tags: jmeter, connection-reset, distributed-testing

I am working on load test for a Website with 240 Users/Load having 5 different scenarios.

I have distributed load within 15 different machines.
I am facing `ERROR java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` many times.

Below is the ERROR log:
[image]

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Please refer the image attached , it has the Error log

Comment: This is common error when server is under stress. Do you have also errors in application in same time?

Comment: yes i have few errors in application too.
but there are many of this Connection Reset errors.
Any resolution to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that your application is not overloaded and operates as expected you can try the steps described in the [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) article, to wit:

- in *user.properties* file:

  ```
  httpclient4.retrycount=1
  hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
  httpclient4.idletimeout=something above zero if your server doesn't send Keep-Alive headers
  ```
- in *hc.parameters* file

  ```
  http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
  ```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: i have already tried the above given setting in user.properties and hc.parameters file.
but still facing same issue of "Connection Reset" :(